# Can't Count dots in Dotsville

Tags: prolog

[image]

This is a table representation of a table containing populated fields known as "dots" that doesn't count '-' and the blank spots. `demo__count_dots_in_column` is where the statement is using `count_dots_in_column` to get results by the input column and be shown be a variable name.

For example:

```
demo__count_dots_in_column :-
    state3,
    count_dots_in_column(1,Count),
    write('>>> number of dots in column 1:  '),
    write(Count1).
```

I've tried:

```
count_dots_in_column(Column,Count) :-
    %count(dot(cell(_,Column),_),
    [red,blue,yellow,green,orange,purple],Count),
```

and:

```
%count_dots_in_column(Column,Count) :-
    %count(dot(cell(R,Column),color(C)),
    [red,blue,yellow,green,orange,purple],Count),
    R \= 0,
    C \= '-',
    dot_count(Column,Count).
```

In short, the first method worked but only returned zeros, is there another predicate method I should do to obtain the accurate numbers?

Also here is the code(s) for this problem: https://github.com/Darkberserker/COG366.git.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfVHb.png)

Comment: I tried fixing the formatting of your code, but it doesn't appear to be correct code(?!?). Can you please fix?

Comment: To second what @Enigmativity said, the code does not look valid. What is `count_the_dots.` by itself doing?

Comment: Thank you @Enigmativity for the formatting and as for count_the_dots, I lost the notes on what it does. Please ignore it for now until I properly fix it.